# Binding of column width to the ColumnWidth property of a DataGrid does only work at the beginning

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I have defined a DataGrid like this

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}"
                         HeadersVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionUnit="Cell"
                         RowHeight="{Binding RowHeight}" ColumnWidth="{Binding ElementName=ColumnAxis,Path=DataContext.RootItem.ItemWidth, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource columnWidthConverter}}" 
                         x:Name="DataTable" 
                         >
```

Important is the part with the binding to the ColumnWidth. In another part of the code I change the DependencyProperty "ItemWidth". For debugging purposes I wrote the following code in the Convert method of the ColumnWidthConverter:

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("Convert, ItemWidth:" + itemWidth);
```

When I now start the application, the Convert method is only called at the beginning but not anymore when I change the DP from the other part of the code. Furthermore the width of the beginning is not taken from the DataGrid but is properly set to auto or something (the width is exactly as long as the longest entry).

I also tried to work with the UpdateSourceTrigger, but I havent worked out the solution.

What is the reason for that and how can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "change the DP from the other part of the code". Is ItemWidth a dependency property?

Comment: Yes, it is. And I change this DP (DependencyProperty) from another part of the code.

Comment: Did you check for any binding error messages in Visual Studio's output window when you run the application in debugger and then change ItemWidth?

Comment: Yes, I did. Unfortunately there arent any =) Then I would know where the prpblem is.

Comment: And you're 100% sure that the object you set ItemWidth on is the same that your binding references, i.e. `DataContext.RootItem` of an element named `ColumnAxis`? Or is it possible that RootItem or even the `DataContext` has changed somehow? It's a bit of guesswork here, since the binding itself looks ok, and you haven't posted any other code.

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure because I tried to initialize it with different values. Then I read them in the Convert method and they are the same. As well the DP used in another part of the code has this start values.

Comment: Another guess: set `Mode=OneWay` just to exclude any issue with two-way binding. Your converter does implement ConvertBack?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7386/discussion-between-hauke-and-clemens)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do the same in code behind and that did not work (with the ColumnWidth property of the DataGrid). But when I change the width for each cell in code behind, then it works.

I do it like this:

```
foreach (DataGridColumn dgc in DataTable.Columns)
{
    dgc.Width = //The DependencyProperty
}
```